# Dynamically injecting Google analytics code via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am trying to inject Google analytics code dynamically to my dom. My code looks like this

```
 (function () {
    const head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];

    var myScript = document.createElement('script');

    myScript.setAttribute('src', 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-1234567-6');
    head.insertBefore(myScript, head.children[1]);

})();

window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); }
gtag('js', new Date());

gtag('config', 'UA-1234567-6');
```

I can see `https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-1234567-6` getting added to my DOM. But the code below it (starting with  `window.dataLayer`) is not getting executed. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `onload` event

```js
(function() {
  const head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];

  var myScript = document.createElement('script');

  myScript.setAttribute('src', 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-1234567-6');

  myScript.onload = function() {
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

    function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); }
    gtag('js', new Date());
    
    console.log('window.dataLayer Executed', window.dataLayer)

    gtag('config', 'UA-1234567-6');
  }

  head.insertBefore(myScript, head.children[1]);

})();
```